# International Collaborative Research - How to coordinate grants and principal investigators?

Tags: research-process

I am coordinating a cross country, cross-university research project on social mobile learning. The research touches on a new learning style that early adopters are trying out. I am the tech partner and support these early adopters (users / lecturers / profs) are sitting all over Asia. To document the 'journey', we are putting the output into academic journals.

A bit more of details:

- To maximize the amount of grant support, it makes sense to apply to both region level (for me its Asia). As well as school level.
- I have participants from different countries (eg. Indonesia, Singapore, Malaysia, Vietnam, China, Hong Kong) and different universities
- In the best case scenario, in my opinion (and my original thought) - i have 1 paper that puts all together as a form of comparison and everyone are co-authors.

But then realistically, each grant requires its own requirement in its principal investigator. And not everyone in other countries may see the benefit to be a part of it.

In hindsight, and this is my current plan -

1. It is probably not possible to go one big bang anyway. The resulting research will be too big too early. The results will not be able to be developed well enough.
2. It would make sense to break things up into smaller chunks that are manageable to build up the research model, theory and experiments. Probably start with some qualitative. In these attempts, i can group lecturers on the same stage, and topic and do them together.

Please help share your experience (and or examples) if you have coordinated international research projects before especially if you only had 1 paper output (for eg to meet a scopus Q1-2 journal)

Comment: The best thing would be that of raising a regional grant for the whole consortium if there is such an opportunity. For instance, if most of the project's members are in Europe, apply to a European call. Maybe there are similar opportunities for other regions.

Comment: Yes, if you apply for multiple grants you need to tailor the applications.  Otherwise, it is unclear what sort of answer you are looking for.